# Ruby - how to retrieve text after a div with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to retrieve the date and time info from the code below (Target Code). I can pull the class name but not date and time.

```
class = events.at_css('div.classTitle b').text
date = events.at_css('.classTitle') ["eventTime"]
time = events.at_css('.classTime span')

p class
p date
p time
```

I get the class name but nil for date and time

Target code

```
<div class="classTitle"><b>Astronomy 101</b></div>

<div class="classTime">

Friday, May 3, 2019<span class="smalltype">&nbsp;at</span>&nbsp;7:00PM</div>

<br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [`Node#content`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node#content-instance_method) method:

This is index.html:

```
<div class="classTitle"><b>Astronomy 101</b></div>

<div class="classTime">

Friday, May 3, 2019<span class="smalltype">&nbsp;at</span>&nbsp;7:00PM
</div>

<br>
```

This is test.rb:

```rb
require 'nokogiri'

events = Nokogiri::HTML(open('index.html'))
date, time = events.at_css('div.classTime').content.strip.split('at')

puts date     #=> Friday, May 3, 2019
puts time     #=> 7:00PM
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried .content and .inner_text but Ruby returns  "undefined method `content' for nil:NilClass" - the content is there - I don't know why it throws a Nil error.

Comment: How have you created `events` object?

Comment: Yes. 

    events = data.css('.classTitle')

Comment: @Gary7 I have updated the answer. Can you check how I have created `events` ?

Comment: Thank you. I will check it out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Remember that Nokogiri will convert `&nbsp;` into `\u00A0` (the NBSP character) which will be returned by `content`, so for cleanliness those should be stripped out. `strip` won't do it. I'd use `tr("\u00A0", '')`. If the data was being parsed and tossed into a database things might break depending on how the DB was configured.